# How to convert Dapper DynamicParameter to DbParameter[]?

Tags: c#, sql, dapper

When using query method in `Dapper.NET` library, the funciton code is here:

```
public IEnumerable<dynamic> Query(IDbConnection conn, string sql, dynamic param = null, IDbTransaction trans = null, bool buffered = true)
{
    return SqlMapper.Query(conn, sql, param as object, trans, buffered);
}
```

Our customer use their own data access library, they dont use `SqlMapper` class in `Dapper` library. So they need to change param to `DbParameter[]`. There are many references with Query method, it is better to only change param object to `DbParameter` array, otherwise we have to modify every reference in our code.

Is there a good way to find a solution to fix this issue? Thanks.

Comment: use IParameter[] which is the interface.

Comment: @Dr.Snitch that doesn't change much, though...

Answer (score 1):

This is not an API that dapper exposes, because it never needs that. To do what you want, you could borrow liberally from the dapper source code to get what you need, but also consider: you cannot create a `DbParameter` in isolation - it is an abstract type. You need to either know in advance what type you actually want, or ask the connection to create the parameters for you.